# Considerations for compiling Fortran code to 64bit?

Tags: compilation, fortran, 32bit-64bit

I'm working on scientific/engineering programs written in fortran for a 32bit unix system and I have to recompile for a new 64bit cluster and having trouble making sense of errors and what changes I should make.

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you post the errors you are having trouble making sense of.

Comment: if you could be more specific (like compiler u use and error messages as pointed out)... i didn't find any trouble compiling my program in my 32 bit laptop as well as 64 bit desktop in my school( i use gfortran and i program in fortran95)

Answer (score 3):

I compile Fortran programs for 32-bit or 64-bit OSes and haven't encountered any problems.  What errors have you seen?   Are you changing it to a parallel program?

A program implemented to the best design philosophy of Fortran >=90 requests numeric types according to the precision that it needs, e.g., using "selected_real_kind" to specify the number of digits needed in a real type. Then the compiler (on the OS and host computer) provides the requested precision if it can, or otherwise the program refuses to run.  If the requested precisions are sufficient to compute the answer, this approach should make a portable program.   It isn't perfect since the numeric computing model isn't totally specified.